# Calling a constexpr method through a reference - is the result a constant expression?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, constexpr

The following code

```
#include <array>

void foo(const std::array<int, 42> &a)
{
  constexpr size_t S = a.size();
}

int main() {}
```

compiles fine in GCC, but fails to compile in clang with the following error message

```
main.cpp:5:28: error: constexpr variable 'S' must be initialized by a constant expression
      constexpr size_t S = a.size();
                           ^~~~~~~~
```

Meanwhile, many posts about `constexpr` issues on SO seem to imply that clang often has better (more pedantic?) support for `constexpr`. So, which compiler would be correct in this case?

Note that both compilers gladly accept the code once the reference parameter is replaced with pass-by-value parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[[expr.const]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2):

> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a *core constant expression* unless
>   the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine
>   ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - [...]
> - an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
>   - it is initialized with a constant expression or
>   - its lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;
> - [...]

Evaluating `a.size()` evaluates the *id-expression* `a`, which "refers to a variable...of reference type" and has no preceding initialization. It is therefore not a core constant expression and so not a constant expression.